# Can't set the current time of Video.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I'm trying to make a website similar to Netflix. Every 5 seconds it does an AJAX request saving the current time in the database (I get the current time of the player via `player.currentTime();`). When I reload the page I want to fetch the last time from the database and set the player to this time. The user has the opportunity to update their settings, controlling if they want the player to start automatically or not.

It seems like the time isn't being set. What am I doing wrong?

```
var player = videojs("video");
var gotTime = 0;

player.ready(function()
{
    player.on("timeupdate", function()
    {
        if(!gotTime)
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: "api/lastposition.php",
                data:
                {
                    v: 16 //video-id
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    if(data != "error")
                    {
                        player.currentTime(data);
                    }
                }
            });
            gotTime = 1;
        }
    });
});
```

Any comments regarding performance optimization are highly appreciated, too!

Comment: If the player is not autoplaying, the timeupdate event won't fire. Is that part of the issue?

Comment: @heff - That's correct. The timeupdate event only fires when the video is playing. I'll try removing that event and see, thank you